# Web Scraping with R: error related to reset of the connection with server

Tags: r, url, web-scraping, download, connection-reset

I have a problem with obtaining data from specific website -  when trying to download raw website data with R 3.6.3 using following example code:

`website_raw <- readLines("https://tge.pl/gaz-rdn?dateShow=09-02-2022")`

The result I got is:

`Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In file(con, "r") : InternetOpenUrl failed: 'the connection with the server was reset'`

`readLines()` method used to work fine on this website but from one week on it fails. I've tried also `download.file()` method: at the beginning the result was the same (error, connection reset) but after setting `options(download.file.method = "libcurl")`, website file starts to download but then it suddenly stops with information:

```
trying URL 'https://tge.pl/gaz-rdn?dateShow=09-02-2022'
Error in download.file("https://tge.pl/gaz-rdn?dateShow=09-02-2022", "test.html") : 
  cannot open URL 'https://tge.pl/gaz-rdn?dateShow=09-02-2022'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file("https://tge.pl/gaz-rdn?dateShow=09-02-2022", "test.html") :
  URL 'https://tge.pl/gaz-rdn?dateShow=09-02-2022': status was 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'
```

I've tried also disabling `Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for HTTP` in Rstudio Global Options but it didn't help. Another solution that I've tested was  `read_html()` from `rvest` package - getting following error:

`Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Send failure: Connection was reset`

Downloading data from other websites works fine though, with all considered methods.

Is there any way I can download data from this website with R?

Any kind of help or suggestion will be highly appreciated

Comment: You can try `RSelenium` package.

Comment: Looks like a handshake error based on ssl. Switch to httr `httr::GET('https://tge.pl/gaz-rdn?dateShow=09-02-2022')`

Comment: Thanks for suggestions: 
1)  `RSelenium` would be hard to use because of server installation necessity - since "external limitations"exists, probably I can't do it on my cpu.

2) I've tried `httr::GET()` method on two machines: on the first it works perfectly fine but on the other (more important one) it doesn't  - error as below:
`Error 'curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle=handle)':
Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10016 milliseconds`

Setting up timeout manually in GET() method didn't help neither.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do both machines have the same httr version?

Comment: Thank you for asking - yes, both have `httr_1.4.2` and `curl_4.3.1`. However, there is a difference between compilers: working machine has `compiler_3.6.3 R6_2.5.0` when the malfuncioned one: `compiler_3.6.3 R6_2.4.1` - I don't think it's a root cause of this issue.

I will be thankful for other comments or suggestions.